# How can I check out a github repo from Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, github

I would like to be able to log the number of words in certain files in a Github repo whenever there is a new push to the repo. I have set up a hook on Github to hit a Django Heroku app url after each push, but I don't know how to run a git pull in python from a Django app running on Heroku. Is it possible to write to the local file system in Heroku?

Comment: Can you expand on what your Django app does? What do you mean when you say your git hook "hit[s] a Django Heroku app url"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check out github repo from Heroku?

from the command line you can pull from heroku easily: `git pull heroku master`

> have set up a hook on Github to hit a Django Heroku app url after each push, but I don't know how to run a git pull in python from a Django app running on Heroku?

Is it a different heroku App (from the one that was deployed) that will be doing the pull?

- **Yes?** then you are going to have issues. Because the pull app needs permission (heroku login) to pull... and it wont have it. Also, b/c of the ephemeral filesystem, even if you login (via `heroku run bash` or the like) to it, the pull app will eventually lose its logged in session (see why below)
- **No?** then don't pull. just use the `os` filesystem libraries to look into the application directory...

> Is it even possible to write to the local file system in Heroku?

Yes and No. You can write to the local filesystem, but its going to get nuked. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Also, with the EFS, each dyno is going to have a different EFS - so each web process is in a way sandboxed.